# In angularjs directive I want to find an id in a HTML and add class on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an HTML which has id "#collapse1" where numeric values are dynamically generated. I want to find that specific id on page load and add a class on it.

My directive code is

```
app.directive('mainSidebar',
  ['$localStorage','$rootScope',function($localStorage,$rootScope){
    return{
        restrict : 'AEC',
        transclude :  true,
        controller : 'SidebarController',
        templateUrl : 'app/sidebar/sidebar.html',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
          element.find('#collapse1').addClass("panel-collapse collapse in");
        }
    }
}])
```

It will be glad if you please help me to write correct code to find and add class on it.

Comment: What's element in `link` function? Is jquery object?

Comment: Pretty sure it should be: `element[0].getElementById("collapse1").addClass("panel-collapse")` also the `.addClass` method accepts one class at a time if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Can you include the template of your directive

Comment: @Adriani6 no addClass syntax is correct. It accepts more than one element separated by space (https://api.jquery.com/addclass/).

Comment: @amicoderozer You're right, however this is not a jQuery object anymore.

Comment: @Adriani6 yeah that's what I suspect too, because jQuery syntax is correct

Comment: @amicoderozer This is one of the reason why you shouldn't use jQuery along side Anuglarjs, apart from the obvious Angularjs digest cycle problems post DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

With the AngularJS framework, use the `ng-class` directive to add and remove classes:

```
<div id="collapse" ng-class="{'panel-collapse': addClass,
                              'collapse': addClass,
                              'in': addClass}" >
</div>

<button ng-click="addClass = !addClass">
    {{addClass ? 'Remove' : 'Add' }}
</button>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-class Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass).

Answer (score 0):

Unless you also loaded JQuery in your project, `element.find('#collapse1')` won't work, because JQLite can't find based on IDs because [it's limited by tag name](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element#angularjs-s-jqlite).

However, you can grab your element with the DOM function and wrap it in an AngularJS element.

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('collapse1')).addClass("panel-collapse collapse in");
```

P.S. georgeawg's answer is the preferred approach, but that assumes you have control over that HTML in order to add `ng-class` to it, which is why I've submitted an alternative answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
element[0].getElementById("collapse1").addClass("panel-collapse collapse in");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("collapse1").addClass("panel-collapse collapse in");
```

Comment: The `addClass` method is a jQuery method. The raw DOM element needs to be converted to a jQuery element.